# Coredata Programming

Tags: core-data

I am newer to core data programming. Can anyone help me on the following issue. 
  I have created a object model wit 4 attributes in 1 entity. image name ,image coordinates,text, features. 
And  set all value to database, and i got all objects from array . Actually i need to compare the current image with database image. If exist i need to load all values from database ie, image name  . image coordinates, text , and features to relevant loaded image. How do I compare self.image with images in the database. 
  Actually i am storing all url of the image to database,. How do i compare with self.image url and image url in the database , and load all values in to current view,.

Please help me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try some things out for yourself and post what you've tried here if you have a specific question about your solution.